# Unable to send mail to hotmail from rackspace cloud

Tags: postfix, spf, dkim, rackspace-cloud, email

I'm having issue sending mail from postfix on a rackspace cloud instance for my domain.

Hotmail says "550 SC-001 (SNT0-MC4-F35) Unfortunately, messages from 198.101.x.x weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. "

Here is the mail log

```
Sep 20 08:02:59 mydomain postfix/smtpd[1810]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 20 08:02:59 mydomain postfix/smtp[1814]: 59CFF4B191: to=<XXXXXX@hotmail.com>, relay=mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=0.19, delays=0.1/0.01/0.06/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, 
status=bounced (host mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 550 SC-001 (SNT0-MC4-F35) Unfortunately, messages from 198.101.x.x weren't sent. 
Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. 
You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Sep 20 08:02:59 mydomain postfix/smtp[1814]: 59CFF4B191: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] while sending RCPT TO
```

I have implemented rDNS, SPF and DKIM they all are looking fine.
I have checked my IP and domain, on most of the spam black lists and it is listed as ok on those, (not listed as spamming IP)

What should I try next?

Comment: There is nothing here that we can help with. Read the message and do what it says.

Comment: And in the meantime configure a smarthost to relay mail for you. There is no circumvention possible. Direct traffic will not go through until Hotmail agrees that the issues have been solved.

Answer (score 3):

Which word in the sentence `Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list.` didn't you understand?

Contact Rackspace and bother them. Then contact Hotmail and bother them. Or better: Let Hotmail talk with Rackspace. How can we mediate between those two parties?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not your fault. But you can help to get that fixed.

As the others mentioned already you should contact Rackspace Cloud Support staff and send them the error report.